# Как сохранять стили в localStorage , а потом их менять

Tags: javascript

```
btnHideRusWords.addEventListener('click', () => {
if(words.length > 0) {
    let layoutEngWords = document.querySelectorAll('.russian-word').forEach(item => {
        item.style.display === 'none' ? item.style.display ='table-cell' : item.style.display ='none'
        localStorage.setItem('hideRusWord', item.style.display)
   })
}
})
```

Повесил на кнопку действие , она ищет по созданной разметки , проходится по массиву, сравнивает что стоит в display ,и меняет по клику , записывает в localStorage.
Подскажите как сохранить стиль после перезагрузки страницы, и чтобы они могли перезаписываться.
То есть у нескольких строчек будет стиль display: table-cell , и по клику будет меняться на none, и храниться в localStorage

Answer (score 0):

localStorage может хранить только строки. Используйте JSON.stringify и JSON.parse соответственно для сохранения в строку и обратно в объект

Для взятия из стоража используйте

```
localStorage.getItem(key)
```

Comment: Сделал так ,но после обновления в localStorage сохраняется, а в разметке ничего не сохраняется после обновления страницы

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте функцию `render(){...}`, которая отвечает за приведение хтмл-ДОМ к описанному в `localStorage` состоянию (берет из `localStorage` данные и меняет классы, если они не соответствуют данным).

По загрузке страницы вызовите `render()`.

По клику пишите в `localStorage` сразу, затем вызовите `render()`.

Можно сказать, как бы, что `localStorage` -- *модель*, а `render` -- *представление*.
В `localStorage` хранятся не классы, а суть состояния.
При каком-либо действии меняется всегда модель.
А хтмл-ДОМ меняется только из `render`.

Существует множество библиотек, упрощающих работу в стиле модель-представление,
например React.